# Extract Entire String Right of the Delimiter from a multi-line string after a match

Tags: python, regex, string

From the multi-line string, I am attempting to extract the entire string right of `=` sign after a match. However, only portion of the string is extracted. 
How can I rectify this problem? I am open to other implementations search/extraction operations as well.

```
import re
s = '''jaguar.vintage.aircards = 2
jaguar.vintage.hw.sdb.size = 512.1 GB
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.firmware = SWI9X15C_05.05.16.02 r21040 carmd-fwbuild1 2014/03/17 23:49:48
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.hardware = 1.0
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.iccid = 8901260591783960689
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.imei = 359225051166726
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.imsi = 310260598396068
jaguar.vintage.hw.tm.model = MC7354
jaguar.vintage.hw.wifi1.mac = 00:30:1a:4e:06:7a
jaguar.vintage.hw.wifi2.mac = 00:30:1a:4e:06:79
jaguar.vintage.part = P34110-002
jaguar.vintage.product = P34101
jaguar.vintage.psoc = 0.1.16
jaguar.vintage.serial = 34110002T0021
jaguar.vintage.slavepsoc1 = 0.1.5
jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release = 4.0.0.41387-201902131138git367fbda8e
'''
# print(s)
# release = (s.split('jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release =')[1]).strip()
# print(release)
#part_number = jaguar.vintage.part = P34110-002
pnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.part =.*?(?=\w)(\w+)"
part_number = re.findall(pnumsrch, s)
print(part_number[0])

# release_number = jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release = 4.0.0.41387-201902131138git367fbda8e
relnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release =.*?(?=\w)(\w+)"
rel_number = re.findall(relnumsrch, s)
print(rel_number[0])
```

> Actual:
>   P34110
>   4
>
> Expected:
>   P34110-002
>   4.0.0.41387-201902131138git367fbda8e

Comment: Use `pnumsrch = r"jaguar\.vintage\.part\s*=\s*(.*)"` and then `relnumsrch = r"jaguar\.vintage\.sw\.app\.release\s*=\s*(.*)"`

Answer (score 0):

Just catch everything that's not a new line [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX8uLe/3):

```
pat = re.compile(r'jaguar\.vintage\.part = ([^\n]+)')
pat2 = re.compile(r'jaguar\.vintage\.sw\.app\.release = ([^\n]+)')

>>> pat.findall(s)

['P34110-002']
>>> pat2.findall(s)

['4.0.0.41387-201902131138git367fbda8e']
```

You also should escape your periods in your pattern.

As mentioned by @WiktorStribiżew, [just `.` is good enough for the `[^\n]` portion](https://regex101.com/r/yX8uLe/4/):

```
pat = re.compile(r'jaguar\.vintage\.part = (.+)')
pat2 = re.compile(r'jaguar\.vintage\.sw\.app\.release = (.+)')
```

Comment: Note that `[^\n]` = `.`

Comment: `pat` returned `jaguar.vintage.part = P34110-002`. I need to capture the string right of `=` sign.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I suppose in single line `.` is good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `.` does not match a newline character by default, you can simply use `.*` to match the rest of the line:

```
pnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.part = (.*)"
```

and:

```
relnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release = (.*)"
```

Comment: How can `relnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release = (.*)"` be modified to extract all characters up to the - from `4.0.0.41387-201902131138git367fbda8e`?

Comment: @RSSregex You can use `relnumsrch = r"jaguar.vintage.sw.app.release = (.*)-"` instead.

Comment: @RSSregex By the way, can you mark the answer you find the most helpful as accepted? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)